# JPA - Only allow column to be updated if it is currently null

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible with JPA/Hibernate to configure a column to be updatable only if it is currently null?

To explain my use-case:

We have a Location entity which can have multiple child Locations. When a Location is persisted, I have a @PostPersist method in an Entity Listener which generates a Materialized Path (https://dzone.com/articles/materialized-paths-tree-structures-relational-database) using IDs and persists it to a `path` column.
We found this is useful for fast lookups. For example, if we want to retrieve all items in a location or any location below it in the hierarchy.

The problem is that once the path is set, I want to ensure that it cannot be updated again. For other fields, I'm able to add `@Column(updatable = false)` but because path must be configured post-persist, I can't just add that annotation in this scenario.

Any suggestions for alternative ways to handle this are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a database trigger for this and map it as `@Generated( ALWAYS )`